# Reading lines from text file in python (windows)

Tags: python, windows, json, io

I am working on a simple import routine that translates a text file to a json file format for our system in python.

```
import json

# Open text file for reading
txtFile = open('Boating.Make.txt', 'r')

# Create picklist obj
picklistObj = dict()
picklistObj['name'] = 'Boating.Make'
picklistObj['items'] = list()

i = 0
# Iterate through each make in text file
for line in txtFile:
    picklistItemObj = dict()
    picklistItemObj['value'] = str(i)
    picklistItemObj['text'] = line.strip()
    picklistItemObj['selectable'] = True
    picklistObj['items'].append(picklistItemObj)
    i = i + 1
txtFile.close()

picklistJson = json.dumps(picklistObj, indent=4)
print picklistJson

picklistFile = open('Boating.Make.json', 'w')
picklistFile.write(picklistJson)
picklistFile.close()
```

My question is, why do I need the "strip"?  I thought that python was supposed to magically know the newline constant for whatever environment I am currently in.  Am I missing something?

I should clarify that the text file I am reading from is an ASCII file that contains lines of text separated '\r\n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python keeps the new line characters while enumerating lines. For example, when enumerating a text file such as

```
foo
bar
```

you get two strings: `"foo\n"` and `"bar\n"`. If you don't want the terminal new line characters, you call `strip()`.

I am not a fan of this behavior by the way.

Comment: It would appear that you are right on this.  It doesn't matter if I open the file as text explicitly using 'U', the behavior is the same.  This seems inconsistent with the "Universal Newline" mentality.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open).

> Python is usually built with universal
>   newline support; supplying 'U' opens
>   the file as a text file, but lines may
>   be terminated by any of the following:
>   the Unix end-of-line convention '\n',
>   the Macintosh convention '\r', or the
>   Windows convention '\r\n'

Comment: Apparently appending the 'U' to the file open mode does not carry through to the iterator (for statement) when reading the file.  Modifying my file open mode to 'rU' did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need the strip() because "for line in file:" keeps the line terminators on the lines.  It's not explicitly stated in the docs (at least in the 2.71 doc I'm looking at).  But it functions in a fashion similar to file.readline(), which does explicitly state that it retains the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in a Python interpreter to see what the language does:

```
open('test1.txt', 'wb').write(b'Hello\nWorld!')
open('test2.txt', 'wb').write(b'Hello\r\nWorld!')
print(list(open('test1.txt'))) # Shows ['Hello\n', 'World!']
print(list(open('test2.txt'))) # Shows ['Hello\n', 'World!']
```

Python does recognize the correct newlines. Instead of using `strip` on your strings, you might want to write `myString.replace('\n', '')` instead. Check the documentation:

```
>>> help(str.strip)
Help on method_descriptor:

strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

>>> help(str.replace)
Help on method_descriptor:

replace(...)
    S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

    Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
    old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
    given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: There is effectively no difference between calling strip and replace as you describe above.

Comment: If you have whitespace at the beginning and ending on your lines that needs to be preserved, `strip` will not suffice for data integrity. If you are reading lines, you may want to call `myString.strip('\n')` at the very least if preserving leading and trailing whitespace is important to you.